# Light: Waves and Particles

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have three questions:

a. How do pictorial representations of electromagnetic waves translate to real life? They're shown as having perpendicular fields in phase,  but how can the strength of a given field,  be it magnetic or electrical,  be perpendicular to the other.  Basically,  how does this wave actually propagate through space?

b.  Einstein theorized that the energy of a single photon increases with raised frequency. Frequency? What charicteristic of a photon makes it periodic so as to possess a frequency?  Does its amount of energy fluctuate, or does this refer to the number photons per second,  etc?

c. How do photons propogate through space,  this is almost  a parellel question to my inquiry in point a.

Comment: This is of course a fascinating question for most of us.  Unfortunately, unless someone way smarter than me knows how to address this in a couple pages, the question is probably too broad for this forum.  My only technical advice is to just forget about the wave-particle "duality" thing; waves are waves, particles are particles and photons are photons.  That photons exhibit both wave and particle like properties just contradicts what we can experience on our macro scale lives, so just don't look too hard for analogies to macro scale phenomena like waves and massive particles. Big help, huh ;)

Comment: There are answers to most of these questions on Physics StackExchange. They do not seem to come to an agreement as to what a photon is, however, so it is not a trivial question.  Experimentally we find that in some experiments it behaves like a particle, in others like a wave. In question (b) The energy of the photon is directly proportional to its frequency; $E=h\nu$ where *h* is Planck's constant and $\nu$ frequency. (see photoelectric effect experiments for proof of energy vs. number of photons).

Comment: Your question must be move their http://physics.stackexchange.com/ because chemistry not study how light is and travel in the space.

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C Disagree on that. Asking what a photon is and how it interacts with matter is a perfectly valid chemical question.

Comment: @Zhe : Disagree too, this is the role of the Quantum Electrodynamic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics "In essence, it describes how light and matter interact and is the first theory where full agreement between quantum mechanics and special relativity is achieved."

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C If that's your view point, then we should be shunting all questions about spectroscopy to physics.SE... :)

Comment: @Zhe does this question ask about spectroscopy ?

Comment: No, but spectroscopy is just light interacting with matter. I feel like your claim would suggest that spectroscopy should not be asked in chem.SE because it is the realm of QED?

Comment: I'm not opposed to moving this specific question to physics, but I think your metric for determining what should be moved does not match mine. I'm just arguing that a basic understanding of a photon and what is does is pretty important in many areas of chemistry. Totally fine if you disagree, but this comment thread is getting a bit long, so I'm just going to leave it at that. Happy to discuss more in chat.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited to physics.se.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're asking the wrong question.

I believe you are confused by the concept of particle-wave duality, which doesn't really exist. The electromagnetic wave is a macroscopic phenomenon that arises because quantum mechanical particles in aggregate may reproduce certain wave-like effects due to the nature of the wave function.

Basically, a photon is just a particle. The energy of this particle is an innate property. At the macroscopic scale, this may manifest as a "frequency" or "color," but neither or those properties is required to explain any physical phenomena.

The photon travels through space like any other particle. You don't ask how an electron travels through space, or if you do and get stuck, then you'll also have the same issue here...

Comment: The whole answer isn't that simple. First most !@#$%^&*( diagrams show a photon as an infinite sine wave which is totally wrong. A particular photon would have a wave pattern more like a harmonically damped oscillator.

Comment: This response doesnt help me cuz it only answers one question and you wrote it like your talking to a Chem professor who knows what a harmonically damped oscillator is,  or what an infinite sine wave is.

Comment: @MaxW I've not seen anyone show a photon as an infinite wave. Generally, the photon is shown with a spread in frequencies centered around a point (this then allows us not to violate the uncertainty principle). [(example)](http://www.pveducation.org/sites/default/files/PVCDROM/Properties-of-Sunlight/Images/photon_flux_light_intensity.png) Again, this is a particle but must satisfy the usual laws with regard to quantum mechanics.

Comment: Zhe - Infinite sine wave. Look at the Wikipedia article for instance... I see it all the time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation

Comment: I'm starting to feel like you didn't actually read my answer... :) The electromagnetic wave is not a photon. You only get that in the limit of a large number of photons.